# trying to use MSAL AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword for a test environment but get the exception 'An Error response was retunred by the OAuth2

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

trying to create a unit test users that flows through the login user flows.

My code is as follows

```
var _authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_settings.Scopes, user, password)
        .WithB2CAuthority(si)
        .ExecuteAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(true);
```

and i get the following error
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'An error response was returned by the OAuth2 server, but it could not be parsed. Please inspect the exception properties for details. '

Using fiddler to see the output i see the following
[image]

I have checked all the other issues on this and still cant find a resolution, any ideas?

app settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCKSB.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you include what value you are passing for `authority` parameter?

Comment: https://ziidmsapp.b2clogin.com/tfp/ziidmsapp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_si, i am calling it with .WithB2CAuthority.

Comment: Note, i have also tried it with this authority and the same error - https://ziidmsapp.b2clogin.com/tfp/ziidmsapp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_si/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Could you try using `tenantID` in your Authority like this: `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-ID}/{policyname}`. Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/desktop-mobile/social-identities#authority-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-and-policy)

Comment: And please confirm whether you registered and modified properties as mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow#register-an-application) to make it work with username password flow.

Comment: thanks for the info but sorry it still does not work, i used the authority of https://adf3b0d5-91a2-403a-9efa-b40b664e9de3.b2clogin.com/tfp/adf3b0d5-91a2-403a-9efa-b40b664e9de3.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_si. I am calling PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_settings.ClientId)
              .WithB2CAuthority(_settings.AuthoritySignIn); and then call -   var _authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_settings.Scopes, user, password)
     .ExecuteAsync()
     .ConfigureAwait(true); and still get the same exception, check to see if the configuration is right, seems like it

Comment: Your Authority value should be like this: `https://ziidmsapp.b2clogin.com/tfp/adf3b0d5-91a2-403a-9efa-b40b664e9de3​/B2C_1_si`

Comment: Allow public client flows
Enable the following mobile and desktop flows:
Yes

App collects plaintext password (Resource Owner Password Credential Flow)

Comment: set the authority as you asked, same issue. - above i added my complete sample program for you to see

Comment: Could you include this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/PhYdrb1.png) of your application to know what account type you selected?

Comment: see above not sure how to add them elsewhere

Comment: Note that, you need to [register](https://i.imgur.com/fufH2MI.png) application by selecting supported account type as _'Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)'_ to make it work with b2c userflows.

Comment: changed to that but the exact same error

Comment: Can you try creating new application with **supported account type** as _'Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)' to make it work with b2c userflows._ and follow steps mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow#register-an-application).

Comment: created a new app exactly as the doc say, sorry still get the same error

Comment: new error Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'AADB2C90108: The orchestration step '1' does not specify a CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId when one was expected.
Correlation ID: 52dfd849-97a2-4f02-88a1-03170d05fda9

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to all my issues were, i need to create a user flow using the new ROPC template. once i used that template i can get the token